# Prevent "runfile(...)" expression in Spyder console

Tags: python, spyder

I'm just getting started with Python and trying to get some easy code-examples to compile. I am using the 'Spyder' Editor and everytime I run code it shows 'runfile(...)' before the actual compiled code in the console.

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: `runfile()` is the function that actually runs your code. Why would you want to prevent it from doing that?

Comment: Because it clutters the console. Especially for programs with short outputs where I might want to compare the results of different runs it is very annoying to have this same message being written there every single time, between successive outputs. I have seen pictures of other compilers which do not put this line there every time, so I was wondering whether disabling this is possible for Spyder as well.

Comment: Easiest example: Compiling the code 'print(3+4)' gives 1.5 lines of said runfile expression (which by the way is colored red, so it looks like an error message) but only one single character, 7, as actual output. This is really annoying.

Comment: Spyder is not a compiler, its is integrated development environment. Spyder runs your code file by calling function `runfile()` on the command line. There is no other way to run code from file in Spyder. You can type code directly on the command line (as you said, `3+4`) and then there will be no loading from files involved. To avoid calling `runfile()`, create a function that executes all the code you need and call it from the command line by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Try including this instead immediately prior to your code. The terminal will now return a clean code only response:

```
cls = lambda: print("\033[2J\033[;H", end='')
cls()
```

Comment: This deletes the whole console content. But only the line runfile... shall be deleted. Especially if the directories are quite long the output of runfile is annoying.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to run the code, instead go to settings, keyboard shortcuts, and look for "run selection" it will have a shortcut assigned to it

Now select all the code and use the shortcut

it will only give you in and out